# using one classe's created object in another class in two seperate runs

Tags: java, object, memory, parameters

I have two .java files that need to run via terminal one after the other. The first creates an object **myObject** which needs to stay in the memory after the run finishes in order to be modified by the second class. myObject is public so both classes have access to it but after the first .java run it's null.

Is there a way to do this?
Or is there a way to keep the object and pass it as an argument to the second class main?

Comment: You need Serialization.

Comment: ..or a database, or data in a file, or...

Comment: thank you @Sanjeev for your immediate response, it really seems this is the answer. My object is really complicated and has a lot of data stored in it and I really wanted to avoid the scenario of creating a data file and then parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the code of the two main methods of the java files into a single main method in the second java file. The main method of the second file could create an instance of the first class, run whatever is has to run, and use the resulting object as input to the processing done by the second class.

If you have to run two main methods, you'll have to persist the state of the first object (for example - serialize it to a file) and the main of the second file would have to restore the object from the file.

Answer (score 0):

When a program exits, all it's memory and resource are reclaimed, not object you created in one program is actually available to another program.

> Is there a way to do this?

You need to either

- have one program which does both operations without being restarted. It could have a command line input to take it's arguments.
- save the object to disk or some other storage so the second program can obtain it.
- use a services where the object lives in a program which is still running when the second program starts.  This is faster but more complicated to implement.

> Or is there a way to keep the object and pass it as an argument to the second class main?

Yes, but only within the same program.  You can have one main() call another main() as these are just like any other methods.